# Jersey Client proper way to execute parallel POST requests

Tags: java, jersey, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm looking for the proper way of executing POST requests using jersey client (with apache http client 4.x)

Since Client instance and WebResource instance are thread-safe, the natural way of coding the method will be:

```
public AuthorizedAccount createAuthTokenFromUserPass(Credentials credentials)
        throws AuthenticationServiceClientException {
    ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/x-protobuf").post(
                              ClientResponse.class, credentials);
    return getAuthorizedAccountFromResponse(response);
}
```

ClientResponse instance is properly released.

When this method is executed from multiple threads, it ends-up by POSTing same credential instance to the server, for each thread.

A solution will be to synchronise the method, but will end-up by executing the POSTs in sequence.

Is there a different way to do it? (avoiding the re-creation of Client instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time trying to figure out what is not working properly, I found out that the issue was not really in jersey client implementation but in my own code. I have used a custom implementation of MessageBodyWriter, where I was not careful enough. I did not read properly the contract of the interface. I have shared an instance variable between call of getSize() and writeTo(), and the MassageBodyWriter is reused.